# Using tkMessageBox without importing Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I'm writing a module where I want to support popup dialogs to indicate errors, but I don't need or want a root window (because I want the module to be independent of the main GUI and share-able between multiple calling applications).  I tried simply doing this:

```
import tkMessageBox
[...stuff...]
if (errorCondition): tkMessageBox.showwarning("My Module","That won't work!")
```

...but when I run it, a root window appears alongside the message box.  I know about the `withdraw()` method, but since I never imported `Tkinter` itself and never instantiated `Tkinter.Tk()`, there's no object for me to use `withdraw()` on.

An alternative that works is to go ahead and import `Tkinter` anyway, so I can create the root window myself and then `withdraw()` it:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
[...stuff...]
if (errorCondition): tkMessageBox.showwarning("My Module","That won't work!")
```

...but even though that works, it seems klunky to bring in a module and instantiate an object just so I can get rid of it.  Plus I don't want to confuse things between this root, and the "real" root in the calling applications.

Going back to the first example, it's obvious that `tkMessageBox` is doing something under the hood to create the root window on its own.  Is there any way I can grab a reference to that root window so I can `withdraw()` it?

(Environment is Windows 7 and Python 2.7.3.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tkMessageBox is built on top of Tkinter, so it is impossible to simply get rid of it: All the functions of the module, like `tkMessageBox.showwarning`, are wrappers of the `_show` function. This function creates a `Message` object, with different arguments depending of the type of dialog you use. `Message` is a subclass of `Dialog`, which in turn is a subclass of `Toplevel`.

`Toplevel` is a Tkinter widget, so the very first line of this module (apart from the comments) where `Dialog` is defined is:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Your second solution is the only way to use tkMessageBox correctly, since you are forced to use (at least internally) Tkinter with it.

**References:**

- [Source code of tkMessageBox](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/da3f4774b939/Lib/lib-tk/tkMessageBox.py)
- [Source code of tkSimpleDialog](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/da3f4774b939/Lib/lib-tk/tkSimpleDialog.py)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially the links.  Even though I can't withdraw that auto-created root window, I can still get the result I want because it won't create that root window in the first place if I've already created one in my own calling application.  (Which I will be, in all cases where I use this module.)

Comment: @JDM The auto-generated root window can be accessed by creating widgets without the `master` argument and then withdraw its parent, like `Tkinter.Button().master.withdraw()`. However, this is an ugly walkaround and your solution is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: tkMessageBox does not use tkSimpleDialog, it uses tkCommonDialog. The code of tkCommonDialog is
[here](http://coverage.livinglogic.de/Lib/lib-tk/tkCommonDialog.py.html)

Comment: Although this link may reply to the question, please post here relevant part answering the OP question, remembering a link can go broken and / or outdated